# Do too small losses impact training?

Tags: neural-networks, mse, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm training a NN using MSE as loss function and SGD as optimizer. The Y values are normalized between -1 and +1. After about 20 epochs the current loss is 0.0085, while it was 0.5 at the beginning of the training. I would like to understand if and how further training is impacted by having a small loss. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drawback of MSE is that its derivative becomes small close to optimum. Assuming we calculate a gradient for one example for weight $w_i$ we have:
$$ 
grad_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \epsilon^2 = 2 \epsilon  \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon = y - \hat{y}$. Close to optimum $\epsilon$ becomes very small and slows down learning.

This is one of the reasons why logloss is preferred in classification problems - its derivative becomes almost constans close to optimum.

So, answering you question, very small loss implies very small gradient and slows down the learning.

As I understand, you problem is regression, not classification, so you cannot replace MSE by logloss. If the results are not satisfactory after 20 epochs, you could try experimenting with different batch sizes and especially with different optimizers than SGD, e.g. Adam. You could also try using absolute loss.